# Mount entry in fstab when connect to a network

Tags: networking, mount, cifs

I have an entry in fstab (Opensuse) which mounts a samba filesystem:

```
//10.39.52.2/Company /media/share cifs credentials=/home/user/file,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

but this mount always fails on startup since connection to network happens at a later moment.

How can I **write a rule** that, each time I connect to a network — the ESSID could be the trigger for wifi, what about cable? — tries to `mount` `/media/share`?

Comment: I think it's typically achieved appending '_netdev' to the options list. Then that entry is queued to be mounted when the correspondent network is available.

Comment: @galegosimpatico, grazie, can you provide an example as an answer based on my sample? I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use your distro, but when facing that, I would do changing the:

```
//10.39.52.2/Company /media/share cifs credentials=/home/user/file,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,f
ile_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

To:

```
//10.39.52.2/Company /media/share cifs credentials=/home/user/file,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,f
ile_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,_netdev 0 0
```

And then rebooting your shares may be mounted at login time.

Comment: It does not work to me. After rebooting it took longer than had the usual message `unable to mount /media/share`

Comment: But does mount OK when mounting manually with the `mount` command, doesn't it?

Comment: yes `sudo mount /media/share` works as expected

Comment: Beats me. But there is a file named _/etc/rc.local_ that may be useful.

Comment: there's a `/etc/rc.d` directory which contains several `.local` files

Comment: Beats me too. But the idea is, no matter which one the specific distribution is, you should always have a way to launch a custom script when the system is _completely_ booted, that would be, let us hope, after all local file systems are (mounted/tried mount) and after all network systems are also (mounted/tried mount). You have to search distribution docs about init scripts practices.